# What should be default value for Blackberry build configuration ? [Debug,Private,or Release]

Tags: blackberry, build

I want to know What should be default value for build configuration ? [Debug,Private,or Release] at the time of 
1) Running application locally on simulator
2) Generating cod file while actually deploying on device/phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration doesn't affect the generated code for BlackBerry projects - it only affects which projects are activated (i.e. that are built when you rebuild your workspace).  So go with whatever you want - I usually pick one configuration and stick with it throughout debugging and release.

Answer (score 1):

I would build in debug mode during development, so that you can step through the code.  When you go to more formal testing, it would probably make sense to build in release mode, so that you're testing a more realistic build of the code.  When you deploy to the device, it's usually best to build in release mode, to make sure you code is optimized to run on the device.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Using build configurations
>
> You can specify several build
>   configurations for your projects. In
>   each build configuration, you can
>   choose projects are active.You can use
>   this functionality to create a set of
>   active projects to build with a
>   BlackBerry Application.

Source:
[BlackBerry JDE Plug-in for Eclipse version 1.0 Online Help](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/4240/BlackBerry_JDE_Plug-in_for_Eclipse_Help.pdf), Ch. "Building a BlackBerry Application"